# Calculate the mysql field during insertion automatically

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have given the image:[image]

Here is one to many relationship in b/w the Place and image.

Now Total_Images field inside the Place table is dependent on the Image table.

Now i want when the user insert the new image inside the Image table then the Total_Images field inside the Place should be auto calculate.

Comment: You can do this using a trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html but I wouldn't store that usually. If you want the number of images, you just do a SELECT COUNT(*) from the images.

Comment: can you give me some concrete example

Comment: you can use the triggers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am working with triggers but still confused.